# Why is iteration through a char vector is faster than the iteration through a string in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am practicing a coding challenge where I have to `reverse the vowels in a string`.

`My first approach failed because of exeeding Time limit.` Here is my first approach using string iteration to reverse the vowels in a string.

```
string reverseVowels(string s) {
    string str = "";
    //storing the vowels from the string into another string
    for (auto x : s)
        if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u' || x == 'A' || x == 'E' || x == 'I' || x == 'O' || x == 'U')
            str = str + x;
    //swapping the vowels
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u' || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'U')
        {
            s[i] = str[count];
            count++;
        }
    }
        return s;
    }
```

`My second approach using the char vector iteration had passed all the tests.` Here is my second approach

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverseVowels(string s) {
  vector<char> v;
  //storing the vowels from the string into vector
    for (auto x : s)
        if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u' || x == 'A' || x == 'E' || x == 'I' || x == 'O' || x == 'U')
            v.push_back(x);
    //swapping the vowels
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u' || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'U')
        {
            s[i] = v[count];
            count++;
        }
    }
        return s;
    }
};
```

Could you explain why my first method failed the tests but second method passed the tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `str = str + x;` with `str.push_back(x);` or `str += x;`, and you'll likely see the same performance as with `vector`.

`str = str + x;` makes a copy of `str`, appends the character to that copy, then makes another copy when assigning back to `str`. As a result, your algorithm is quadratic, for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're doing `str = str + x`, that creates an unnecessary copy of `str`, but `std::vector::push_back` or `std::string::push_back` appends a character to the vector or string, which is much faster than creating a copy of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

`str = str + x`
this creates an additional copy of str while copying.
`std::vector::push_back`
this straight appends to the vector string